# Keycloak: Prohibit issuance of an id_token when using Oauth2/OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

We want to provide plain Oauth2 for an external application which we do not trust. We are using the default OpenID Connect provider in Keycloak. The problem is: When the external application calls `/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token` with `scope=openid`, then it gets an access_token and an **id_token**. The latter contains user information which we do not want to reveal to the application. Any ideas how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unassign all `Client scopes` for that particular client and/or switch off `Add to ID token` in particular protocol mappers. Also consider to disable `Full Scope Allowed` in the `Scope` tab and unassign all roles.

Comment: This does not remove the `id_token` itself but it removes all user related data (name, email,...) from it which is as much as we want. Thanks a lot! (I spend days on it and did not make any progress)